# Illustrator - Select Pen Tool Programmatically

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

This is a simpler version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461170/illustrator-activate-tool-programmatically

How do I select the pen tool in Illustrator programatically? The pen tool is not recordable via actions. Using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The pen tool is not included as a recordable action. There may be a way around this depending on how you plan on using the pen tool.

More here info here:  https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/automation-actions.html

Comment: Thanks Carrie, the pen tool is unselectable from Actions, so I'm not sure if that's the answer.